# Where to start on MS Dynamics

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

Can some one tell me where to start learning Microsoft Dynamics? Maybe a book or online would help

My main background is C# and mostly asp.net and services last 5 years, trying to start learning Dynamics any help would be appreciated.

Comment: first thing to do it google microsoft dynamics. There are 4 very different systems under the dynamics umbrella. CRM, GP, NAV & CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi start by gathering the pdf e-books available on the internet, depending on what version you are working with, I'd assume AX 2009 / 2012, so here some documentation I am aware of;

Introduction to Dynamics AX 2009
Dynamics AX 2009 Cook Book
MorphxIT
Inside Dynamics AX 2009

Also if you are with a customer or partner you can get your hands on the Development packs.

If you are skilled with C#, x++ will not be a problem for you the languages are very similar.